# Почему на вот это выражение в if ошибка?

Tags: java, логические-выражения

Почему на вот это выражение в `if` ошибка?

**Выражение:**

```java
if (Layout1BottomVar.equals("NormBarPinned") || Layout1BottomVar.equals("NormBarUnpinned"))
```

**Ошибка:**

```java
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Layout1BottomVar   у тебя null..... в тексте ошибки прям так и написано

Comment: замените на `"NormBarPinned".equals(Layout1BottomVar)` и т.д. или `Objects.equals(Layout1BottomVar, "NormBarPinned")`